# Inverse of sum of matrices has lower norm than the inverse of summand(s)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite, matrix-norms

For symmetric $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $\mathbf{c}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$, when $\mathbf{A}\succ 0$ and $\mathbf{B}\succeq 0$, I want to show that
\begin{align*}
           \|(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|
        \leq \|\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|.
        \end{align*}
I have a feeling it would have something to do with determinants or eigenvalues, but I am not sure how to go about the proof.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Hello. When a statement is in principle numerically falsifiable, the user who requests for a proof is expected to exercise due diligence and carry out a numerical experiment to verify the truthfulness of the statement, so that other users will not waste their time on trying to prove a false statement.

Comment: @user1551 , apologies for that. But I still fail to see how my statement is numerically falsifiable. Can you please provide your counter-example? Thanks!

Comment: It is *your* responsibility to run a numerical experiment (generate, say, 10000 triples of $(A,B,c)$) to see if there are any counterexamples. If there aren't any, there is a chance that the statement is correct. Otherwise, there is no need to ask your question.

Comment: Ah, understood. I misunderstood your comment to mean that you had already thought of a counterexample and that it was a waste of time to consider my problem. I'll update the post with the simulation results by tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a counterexample:

$$
\mathbf A = \left[\begin{matrix}5 & -3\\-3 & 5\end{matrix}\right],\quad 
\mathbf B = \left[\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right], \quad 
\mathbf c = \left[\begin{matrix}3\\-4\end{matrix}\right].
$$
We find that
$$
\|(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf B)^{-1}\mathbf c\|^2 \approx \|\mathbf A^{-1}\mathbf c\| + .023
$$

Here's the script I used to generate a "nice" counterexample:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint, rand
from scipy.linalg import norm, inv, det, eig
from sympy import Matrix, latex

for _ in range(100):
    ran = 2
    L = randint(-ran,ran+1,size=[2,2])
    A = L@L.T
    L = randint(-ran,ran+1,size = [2,1])
    B = L@L.T
    try:
        M = inv(A@A) - inv((A+B)@(A+B)) 
    except:
        continue
    if det(M) < -1e-6:
        print(A)
        print(B)
        break
else:
    print('none found')
```

Once you have a suitable $A$ and $B$, a suitable vector $c$ can be found taking $c$ equal to the eigenvector of $M = A^{-2} - (A+B)^{-2}$ associated with a negative eigenvalue (why?). By rounding the entries of a multiple of this vector $c$, we can get a "nicer" suitable vector $c$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter example man! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Assume for symmetric $\mathbf{A}, \mathbf{B}$ the proposition does hold,
\begin{align*}
\|(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|^2 &\leq \|\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|^2,\\
(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-2} &\preccurlyeq \mathbf{A}^{-2},\\
(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1} &\preccurlyeq \mathbf{A}^{-1},\;\;\;\;\text{(F. Zhang, ``Matrix Theory'', Theorem 7.9.)}\\
\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} &\succcurlyeq \mathbf{A},\;\;\;\;\text{(F. Zhang, ``Matrix Theory, Theorem 7.8.)}\\
\mathbf{B} &\succcurlyeq 0,\\
\end{align*}
which is true.

Alternatively, we can also start by assuming that the proposition is false
\begin{align*}
\|(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|^2 &\gt \|\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{c}\|^2,\\
(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-2} &\succ \mathbf{A}^{-2},\\
(\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B})^{-1} &\succ \mathbf{A}^{-1},\;\;\;\;\text{(F. Zhang, ``Matrix Theory'', Theorem 7.9.)}\\
\mathbf{A} + \mathbf{B} &\prec \mathbf{A},\;\;\;\;\text{(F. Zhang, ``Matrix Theory, Theorem 7.8.)}\\
\mathbf{B} &\prec 0,\\
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

Hence proved that the proposition is true.

Comment: Given the counter example by @Ben Grossmann , this proof is obviously false (or at the very least is incomplete). But I cannot seem to spot the mistake is there is one.

Comment: How do you get $(A+B)^{-2}>A^{-2}$?

Comment: @tomasz
\begin{align}
\left\| \left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{c} \right\|^2 &\gt \left\| \mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{c} \right\|^2,\\
\mathbf{c}^{\top}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-\top}\left(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{c} &\gt \mathbf{c}^{\top} \mathbf{A}^{-\top}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{c},\\
\mathbf{c}^{\top}(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-2}\mathbf{c} &\gt \mathbf{c}^{\top} \mathbf{A}^{-2}\mathbf{c},\\
\mathbf{c}^{\top}\left((\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-2} - \mathbf{A}^{-2}\right)\mathbf{c}  &\gt 0,\\
(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})^{-2} - \mathbf{A}^{-2}  &\succ 0
\end{align}